# My state value keeps resetting inside a function inside my hook; why?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

If I call incrementPage() from the component that uses this hook, pageNum is always '0' and I don't understand why.

The setPageNum(prevPage => ...} works but what if I just wanted to access the 'pageNum' value.  How could I do that?

I imagine a 'ref' would work but I feel like that's improper and I'm doing something wrong?

When am I supposed to be using useCallback in these hooks?

```
export function useCatImages() {
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
  const [pageNum, setPageNum] = useState(0);
  const MAX_PAGE = 3;

  const fetchImages = useCallback(async (page) => {
    ...
  }, []);
  
  const incrementPage = useCallback(() => {
    console.log('pageNum: ', pageNum);  // THIS IS ALWAYS '0'
    setPageNum((prevPage) => {
      return (prevPage < MAX_PAGE)
        ? prevPage + 1
        : prevPage;
    });
  }, [pageNum]);

  return {
    images,
    incrementPage,
  };
}
```

Comment: Depends on how `incrementPage` is used by the consumer of `useCatImages`

Comment: Here's a code sandbox that shows your code working as expected (`pageNum` increments on each button click). As @CertainPerformance suggested, showing how you're using `useCatImages` in another component should help debug https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-overflow-74250359-5tqxjb

Comment: i'm passing it as a callback to another function.  thanks for the codesandbox.  so i guess because i'm passing it in as a callback, it always stays as 0 for some reason?

Comment: Only if you're implementing it wrong in the consumer - again, need to see the consumer to say why

Comment: I'll try to make a codesandbox.  Thanks @CertainPerformance